Il mistero della risposta scomparsa
Sono sicuro di aver risposto a una domanda inerente la forma italiana del detto napoletano “Ogni scarrafon' ie bell' a mamma soa”, ma ora vedo che è scomparsa, e con essa sono scomparse le variazioni della reputazione che avevo perso o acquisito.
È possibile che tutto ciò sia regolare?
È possibile, altresì, che l'utente che postò la domanda l'abbia poi cancellata, così influendo sulla reputazione che avevo perso o acquisito?
English version
1) I posted an answer.
2) The answer got some votes.
3) The answer vanished because, as it seems according to @Charo, the OP deleted the question to which I answered.
Question: How is it possible that an OP can delete a question which got votes, negative or positive?

Questions can be deleted by the OP.

The policy on meta is to have questions available in English. So please make an effort and translate your question into English. (In my opinion the best thing is to post both in Italian and in English).

@Charo, but, as far as I know, the OP, except the case in which he/she is a moderator, cannot delete a question whose answers have got votes, be them negative or positive.

If you read the help carefully, it answers your question in detail:

Users can delete their own questions if the question:
-- has zero answers
-- only one answer, but that answer has no upvotes 
Answers are automatically deleted when the question they're attached to is deleted. Such answers are automatically undeleted when the question is undeleted, except for answers that were deleted before the question was deleted.

